# How to delete duplicate data with a condition

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have witten a query to delete the duplicate data

```
DELETE FROM tbl_test t
  WHERE t.ROWID > ANY (SELECT b.ROWID
                          FROM tbl_test b
                         WHERE b.ser_no = t.ser_no
                       );
```

This gives me 199 records which is correct .
Since the duplicate records have status L,F or R . So I have to delete all teh records which are F or R.

For example if I have two records

```
ID  ser_no   Sta
1    20       L
2    20       F
3    15       R
4    15       L
5    89       L
6    89       F
7    10       R
8    10       R
```

So only one of the duplicate of Status R or F should be Deleted . There is no case in which both dupliate has LL or F,R Status
So I tried

```
DELETE FROM tbl_test t
      WHERE t.ROWID > ANY (SELECT b.ROWID
                              FROM tbl_test b
                             WHERE b.ser_no = t.ser_no
                             AND b.Sta<>'L'
                           );
```

It did not work. It displays 125 records.

The final result should be

```
ID  ser_no   Sta
    2    20       F
    3    15       R
    6    89       F
    8    10       R
```

Comment: Are you aware that in Oracle ROWID is a pseudocolumn? To learn more of its inner working try: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `delete` statement, it works as described in rules and gave correct output for your examples:

<sup>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/41c7d/1)</sup>

```
delete from tbl_test t 
  where t.sta in ('F', 'R') and exists ( 
      select 1 from tbl_test b 
        where b.ser_no = t.ser_no 
          and (sta='L' or (sta<>'L' and b.id<t.id)) )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
DELETE FROM tbl_test t
      WHERE t.ROWID in (SELECT max(b.ROWID)
                              FROM tbl_test b
                             where b.Sta in('R','F')
                             group by b.ser_no,b.Sta
                           );
```

Comment: That means this record should be duplicate. Match your table data

Comment: Your question should be specify actual data and duplicate data.